# Out of range float values are not JSON compliant with Django render

Tags: json, python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework

I'm working with `django-restframework` and I'm using `JSONRenderer` to render my return response.

But I always get errors like:

```
    response = response.render()
  File "C:\Users\Domob\Desktop\dev\venv_bv_crm\lib\site-packages\django\template\response.py", line 106, in render
    self.content = self.rendered_content
  File "C:\Users\Domob\Desktop\dev\venv_bv_crm\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\response.py", line 70, in rendered_content
    ret = renderer.render(self.data, accepted_media_type, context)
  File "C:\Users\Domob\Desktop\dev\venv_bv_crm\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\renderers.py", line 104, in render
    allow_nan=not self.strict, separators=separators
  File "C:\Users\Domob\Desktop\dev\venv_bv_crm\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\utils\json.py", line 25, in dumps
    return json.dumps(*args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\python3\lib\json\__init__.py", line 238, in dumps
    **kw).encode(obj)
  File "D:\python3\lib\json\encoder.py", line 199, in encode
    chunks = self.iterencode(o, _one_shot=True)
  File "D:\python3\lib\json\encoder.py", line 257, in iterencode
    return _iterencode(o, 0)

ValueError: Out of range float values are not JSON compliant
```

My main logic codes are like below, there are some `nan` values in my data dict:

```py
class BasicView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = ...
    serializer_class = ...
    filter_backends = ...
    renderer_classes = [JSONRenderer, BrowsableAPIRenderer]
  

   @action(methods=['get'], url_path='dash', detail=False)
    def dashboard(self, request):
        try:
            data = a = [{"k": 1, "v": float('nan')}, {"k": 2, "v": float('inf')}]
            return Response({"data":data})

        except json.decoder.JSONDecodeError:
            print(f"empty result with {request.user.id}")
            return Response(status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)

        except:
            import traceback as tb
            print(tb.format_exc())
            return Response(status=status.HTTP_500_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
```

How can I get the right response?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

[JSON](https://www.json.org/) doesn't have the concept of `NaN`, it can only represent numbers that represent actual numbers. (It also doesn't have some other floating-point number concepts like Infinity and negative zero.)

You'll have to ensure you don't have `NaN` floats in the data you're serializing to JSON.

Comment: hi, I am having the same error, is there any other solution like allowing Nan?

Comment: @AvinMathew You can transfer all these `NaN` ，`Infinity` , `-Infinity` values while using `json.loads`

Comment: @AvinMathew I mean json.loads(parse_constant=your_own_method)

Comment: Is this still true? If I use the `json` library in python, I see it parses `NaN` just fine. `df = pandas.DataFrame([[1, "hello"], [numpy.nan, None]], columns=['a','b'])`; `df_as_json = json.dumps(df.to_dict(orient='split'))` -> `'{"index": [0, 1], "columns": ["a", "b"], "data": [[1.0, "hello"], [NaN, null]]}'`; `json.loads(df_as_json)` -> `{'index': [0, 1], 'columns': ['a', 'b'], 'data': [[1.0, 'hello'], [nan, None]]}`

Comment: Oh hang on. https://github.com/psf/requests/issues/5767 says "stdlib's `json.dumps` has `allow_nan` option which is `True` by default and consequently generates invalid JSON by default"